# Sticky menu not staying within container

Tags: html, css

I've built a foreign language glossary and I'm using alphabet letters as a vertical sticky key or menu down the side. I have split the vertical key into two halves and the left-hand key alphabet-barL works fine on the extreme left within the container. How can I make the right-hand key alphabet-barR stay within the same container as the left-hand one, but on the right-hand side?

I've tried giving the container a fixed width, I've tried making the right-hand key float right, but neither works. Giving the right-hand key a fixed position of right:0 (obviously) puts the key on the right vertical edge of the browser window, which is not what is needed.

css

```
.alphabet-barL { position:fixed; top:30%; }
.alphabet-barL a { display:block; text-align:center; padding:6px 6px; font-family:sans-   serif; font-size:1em; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}
.alphabet-barL a:hover, a:active { background-color:#ed8725;}
.alphasquare {background:#21A7Ab;}

.alphabet-barR { position:fixed; top:30%; float:right; }
.alphabet-barR a { display:block; text-align:center; padding:6px 6px; font-family:sans-serif; font-size:1em; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}
.alphabet-barR a:hover, a:active { background-color:#ed8725;}
.alphasquare {background:#21A7Ab;}
```

html

```
<div class="alphabet-barL">
   <a href="#A" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">A</a>   
   <a href="#B" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">B</a> 
   <a href="#C" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">C</a> 
   <a href="#D" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">D</a>
   <a href="#E" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">E</a> 
   <a href="#G" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">G</a> 
   <a href="#H" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">H</a> 
   <a href="#I" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">I</a> 
   <a href="#J" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">J</a>
   <a href="#K" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">K</a> 
   <a href="#L" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">L</a>
   </div>

   <div class="alphabet-barR">
   <a href="#M" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">M</a> 
   <a href="#N" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">N</a> 
   <a href="#O" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">O</a>
   <a href="#P" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">P</a> 
   <a href="#R" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">R</a> 
   <a href="#S" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">S</a> 
   <a href="#T" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">T</a> 
   <a href="#U" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">U</a>
   <a href="#V" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">V</a>
   <a href="#Y" class="alphasquare" title="Go to this letter">Y</a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Here's a demo in codepen: https://codepen.io/samuelsarin/pen/KKdJgeX

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a wrapper around the right-hand, vertical, fixed, alphabet bar and give it the following styling:

```
.wrapper { width: 25px; float: right; }
```

Floating the wrapper to the right pushes the wrapper and the (right-hand) bar it contains to the right-hand inner edge of the wrapper's container. The wrapper's 25px width matches that of the bar it contains. The codepen demo is updated to reflect this.